# Echoing a pseudo column value after a COUNT

Tags: php, mysql

Please don't beat me if this is elementary.  I searched and found disjointed stuff relating to pseudo columns.  Nothing spot on about what I need.

Anyway... I have a table with some rows.  Each record has a unique ID, an ID that relates to another entity and finally a comment that relates to that last entity.

So, I want to COUNT these rows to basically find what entity has the most comments.

Instead of me explaining the query, I'll print it

```
SELECT entity_id, COUNT(*) AS amount FROM comments GROUP BY entity_id ORDER BY amount DESC
```

The query does just what I want, but I want to echo the values from that pseudo column, 'amount'

Can it be done, or should I use another method like mysql_num_rows?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have the row in, say, `$row`, you can simply use the value of `$row['amount']`.

Comment: Ignacio... you got it.  As you can see, I am really new at this.  Thank you very much.

Comment: If it needs to be changed slightly, by the definition of "needs", it does not work :p My point was that if he did `$row = mysql_fetch_row(...)`, then he'd have to use `$row[1]`.

Answer (score 3):

It's just the same as with the other column – you use the [`mysql_fetch_*`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) family.

Note that moving to the [Mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) extension is encouraged. See [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.overview.php) why.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Artefacto.  Will do my research on improved MYSQL.  I am SO behind in everything.

Comment: I thought we could send private messages here.  Anyhow, do you do this for a living?  How long does it take to assimilate the new MYSQL methods in PHP5?  Obrigado!

Comment: @rob that would depend on several factors, including previous experience with databases, PHP, MySQL, etc. It is certainly easier to get familiar with a certain client database API than to learn SQL, for instance. And no, I've never programmed in PHP professionaly (only in Java).